# How can I assign 1 bucket policy to multiple S3 buckets using for_each in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to for loop and get get the interpolation correct:

```
variable "my_bucket_names" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "b1",
    "b2",
  ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "tf-thing-audit-policy" {
  for_each           = toset(var.my_bucket_names)
  bucket = ${each.key.id} 
...
```

Is there a way I can interpolate on the `bucket` value?

### Error:

```
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
```

Comment: `each.key` is a string and not a map or an object. Your interpolation is completely fine. The issue is you are attempting to access a `null`. What value do you want for the argument `bucket`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each.key` is of type `string`, not an object or a map so doing `.id` will result in `null` as it doesn't exist.

Using the value of `each.key` directly will be fine for what you're trying to do (assigning 1 bucket policy to multiple buckets). You also don't need `{}` as you don't need to do any string interpolation for the `bucket` argument of `aws_s3_bucket_policy`.

`aws_s3_bucket_policy` just requires the [bucket name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_policy#argument-reference) which is `each.key`:

> bucket - (Required) **The name of the bucket** to which to apply the policy.

This should work perfectly fine, provided you specify a valid bucket policy:

```
variable "my_bucket_names" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "b1",
    "b2",
  ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "tf-thing-audit-policy" {
  for_each = toset(var.my_bucket_names)
  bucket = each.key
  policy = jsonencode(...)
}
```